# php: mysql db connection ok but can't perform query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm learning php and right now I'm figuring out dbs. Was following up with a tutorial on YT and got stuck in the following:

"retrieve all records from table"

Specifically, I can connect to my DB no prob, but when I perform the select query it prints nothing

Here's my code...

```html
<?php

 //error_reporting(0);
 
 require 'connect.php';
 
 $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sample-objects");
 
 //$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM sample-objects");
 
 print_r($result); 
 

?>
```

and my connection script

```html
<?php

 $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
 
 // echo $db->connect_errno,"\n";
 
 if ($db->connect_errno)
 {
  echo "error: ",$db->connect_error; /* Imprime descripción de error de DB */
  //die("Site offline");
 }

?>
```

I don't get any errors from "connect.php" and I do have 2 records in my db (did so from phpmyadmin)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having checked for errors on your query would have signaled the error in your table name containing a hyphen:

```
SELECT * FROM sample-objects
                    ^ that is the problem character
```

where MySQL is interpreting that as `sample MINUS objects` thinking you want to do math here.

Either you wrap it with ticks (*careful,* those are not single quotes `'`) copy/paste as shown:

```
SELECT * FROM `sample-objects`
```

or rename it with an underscore (rename your table first before using this example)

```
SELECT * FROM sample_objects
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

---

Example from the manual on [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
if (!$mysqli->query("SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

I also noticed you commented out `//error_reporting(0);`

That actually turns error reporting off. You need to turn it on and to display:

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thank you! That got me unstuck :)

I had checked in myphpadmin and it showed the select query without any problems, eclipse didn't highlight the error so I thought I was safe. I'll be more careful now, just getting the hang of it.

Once again, thanks!